# How to import table in Excel?

Tags: tables, excel

I would like to know if it is possible to copy a table from  Excel with the configurations to Latex.

I use Microsoft Excel 2016 for Max OS X.

Thank you!

Comment: [extract-data-from-excel-file-with-lualatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247999/extract-data-from-excel-file-with-lualatex) or  [getting-data-dynamically-into-latex-from-a-spreadsheet](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198026/getting-data-dynamically-into-latex-from-a-spreadsheet) [excel2latex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/) or use datatool [formatting-complex-table-from-csv-using-datatool](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17618/formatting-complex-table-from-csv-using-datatool) or [csv2latex](http://brouits.free.fr/csv2latex/)

Comment: If any of the links @Nasser has posted fit your needs, or this one: [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49414) please let us know and we can close this question as a duplicate. If you are using TeXShop there is a "Paste Spreadsheet Cells" menu item in the Macros menu which will do what you want. The same functionality is available with any Mac scriptable editor with a little extra work.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for a macro something like this [Excel to Latex](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex)

But, please also see the following known issues ...

```
KNOWN ISSUES
~~~~~~~~~~~~
Office Mac: "Copy to clipboard" appends extra null (\0) characters.
Office Mac: Performance is worse than in Windows, converting large ranges might
take minutes or hours.
Office Mac: The functionality is accessible only through the "Format" menu.
Office Mac: The dialog is modal (Windows: modeless).
All: Color not (yet) supported.
```

However, I am using the same, without any problem (but with an older version). Just copy the latex table and don't use "Copy to clipboard".

Just use this .xla file in your excel sheet, go to format option in excel and chose to convert table to latex.